# Deployed VS 2010 WPF Application Cannot Update Log Files Unless in Administrator Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I have a WPF Application that uses nLog to write out log files. On my machine it writes out the log file successfully.
I have created a deployment project, and generate an install, which installs it into program files . The install works successfully, but when the application is run, the log file generated by nLog is not created. No exception is thrown.

I am running Windows 7.

The log file is being created in the same directory as the executable.

If I run the deployed application in Administrator mode, the log file is created successfully.

How can I get past this? Would signing the executable help? Do I really need this to run in admin mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to log to a different location. You *should not* write to `C:\Program Files` from your application. Instead, move your log files to something like `%APPDATA%\Your Company\Your Application\Logs`.

By using `%APPDATA%`, your application can run on different versions of Windows, and if they change the structure of the standard directories (like between XP and Vista), your application will log to the correct location still.

Answer (score 2):

The Program Files directory is properly locked down.  Change the application to write the log file to an unrestricted location.  (I prefer the all users' application data directory.)

Answer (score 1):

What others have said: the program files directory is locked down. You need to use another folder location to log towards.

I have had great success logging to the UserProfile special folder so that my logs wind up in this folder structure:

C:\Users\CurrentUser\My Docuements\Company Name\ApplicationName\

See this link for some useful information on special folderes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Folders

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents
```